# AngularJS and login page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a question and I wanted to know what is the best to create a login page.

Actually, I create a ng-view root (in my app.js 'when...then') called /login.

The problem with this method is that I have to include my static HTML in other files using ng-include . (I dont need this static HTML in my login page. so ng-view is the first marke-up after the body one)

for example, I have my index.html body that looks like:

```
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

My partials login contains a form to connect (simple form) (/login)

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="login" placeholder="login">
    <input type="text" ng-model="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
```

My other files like (/users, /clients, /billing etc...) looks like :

```
<div ng-include="partials/menu.html"></div>
My custom content
<div ng-include="partials/footer.html"></div>
```

Is this a good way? Or does it exist a better one?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Perhaps, you should post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: take a look at the angular-app security module, there are some really good ideas : https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the `ng-include`s for menu and footer in each and every partial (except `login.html`), you could place them in the `index.html` and hide them when you are on the `/login` page as follows:

In your `index.html`:

```
<body ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></ng-include>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <!-- same for footer as for menu -->
</body>
```

In your `menu.html`:

```
<nav ng-hide="isActive('/login')">
    <!-- ...-->
</nav>
```

In the new controller `MenuCtrl`:

```
.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {             
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };
}])
```

You can also use this, to style your login page completely differently (e.g., different background colors etc.), when you do something like this in your index.html:

```
<body ng-class="{MyLoginTheme: isActive('/login')}" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
```

Comment: Is this the actual best solution ?